# Entity Framework: Mocking with JustMock

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, justmock

I've just installed the **Telerik.JustMock.EntityFramework** package, and i am trying it.

I've tried this:

```
var ctx = EntityFrameworkMock.Create<MyDbContext>().PrepareMock();

var source = new List<MyEntity>()
            {
                new MyEntity(){ Description = "asd" },
                new MyEntity(){ Description = "asd2" },
            };

ctx.MyEntities.Bind(source);
```

And when i retrieve the data doing this, it works:

```
ctx.MyEntities.ToList();
```

But if i do the next:

```
ctx.Set<MyEntity>().ToList();
```

It returns an empty collection.

Do you know what i am doing wrong? Or do you know how can i mock the collection that my context returns? Because i am using the repository pattern and i want to test the methods from the repository, that is working with a given context.

Btw, this is my **MyDbContext** class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking a DbContext can be difficult because there are a lot of moving parts that the context is keeping up with.  I've had success using a library that helps to set up an in-memory data context.  Not exactly a direct answer, but I've run into lots of problems attempting a straight mock with other mocking frameworks

http://effort.codeplex.com/

This library is available as a nuget package.

Comment: I know this is not the answer, but i think i can consider it as one. I've just tried effort and it works great! Thanks!